Substitute numpy array values for specific index
I have an image array (shape : 256, 256, 3).
There is an index as below.
array([[  2, 254],
       [  2, 255],
       [  3, 252],
       ...,
       [148, 169],
       [148, 170],
       [149, 169]], dtype=int64)

I could know index values of image array with below code.
read_image(image).numpy()[idx[:,0], idx[:,1]]

Index values of image array would be as below. (shape: (11978, 3))
array([[145, 161, 174],
       [139, 155, 168],
       [157, 171, 184],
       ...,
       [144, 161, 169],
       [144, 161, 169],
       [146, 163, 171]], dtype=uint8)

I have an another array as below (size: (11978,))
array([150, 150, 130, ..., 120, 150, 160])

I want to change index values of 3 channels with above array.
For example, image array of [2, 254, 3] position would be changed to [150, 150, 150], which is RGB.
Image array of [149, 169, 3] position would be changed to [160, 160, 160].

Can you provide an explicit [mre] with reduced dimensions? e.g. (4,4,3) instead of (256,256,3) and likewise for the index

The following code demonstrates how to solve your problem by a smaller example. It creates a 4×4 all-red RGB image, provides 2 index values ([2, 2] and [3, 0]) and corresponding grayscale values (255 and 127), then assigns the grayscale values at the index values:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Produce 4×4 red RGB image
img = np.zeros(shape=(4,4,3), dtype=np.uint8)
img[..., 0] = 255
# Provide indices: almost center and lower left corner
idx = np.asarray([[2, 2], [3, 0]])
# Provide desired gray values: white for center, 50% gray for corner
grays = np.asarray([255, 127])
# Assign gray values at indices (add new axis: broadcast along channel dimension)
img[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]] = grays[:, np.newaxis]
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()

Here, img corresponds to your 256×256 RGB image, idx corresponds to your array([[  2, 254], ..., [149, 169]], dtype=int64), and grays corresponds to your array([150, ..., 160]).
The result looks as follows:

